# c++ newbie - pthread providing it's state to another pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am a newbie in c++ working on what should be a pretty basic file read and then process data functionality and I keep getting stuck on being able to at least provide a "state" of on thread to another so that data could be consumed. This just maybe something really basic that I am overlooking - could use some insight into using pthreads in c++.

Bellow is some basic extracted code that functions OK, reads the file and provides data to be processed. Another thread that will process the data needs to know the state of this one.
What would be the best strategy? I am attempting to request the state of the thread through a function from another thread but receive incorrect response.

```
Reader::Reader(){

    _threadId = 1; 
    _msg = NONE; // enum NONE, READ, STOP
    active = false;
    pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, 0);
}

Reader::~Reader(){

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&_mutex);
}

void Reader::read(){

    _msg = READ;
    active = true;

    pthread_create(&_threadId, 0, work, this);
}

void * Reader::work(void *myselfreader){

    Reader * reader = (Reader*)myselfreader;

    reader->loop();

    pthread_exit(0);

    return 0;
}

void Reader::loop(){

    while(active){

            pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);

            switch(_msg){

                case READ:

                    // do the reading of the IO file - which works fine                 
                    // once done reading the file - the _msg is set to STOP

                    break;

                case STOP:

                    stopThread();

                    break;


                default:
                        break;
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
        }

    return;
}

void Reader::stopThread(){

    active = false;

    _msg = ENC_NONE;

    pthread_join(_threadId, 0);
}

/*****************/

int Reader::getReaderState(){

    // another thread needs to know the state of this thread
    // 
    return _msg // ??
    return active // ??
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have race condition somewhere in your code.

You need to protect your `_msg` variable with mutex. Every time you need to update `_msg` variable request mutex, update variable and close the mutex. You need to do the same thing for the reading in `getReaderState()` function - acquire mutex, copy variable into temp, release mutex and return temp variable.

For easy and error-prone usage, you should create getter and setter function for accessing `_msg` field which will be guarded by the same mutex (and not the one that you are already using):

```
void setMsg(int msg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&msg_mutex);
    _msg = msg;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&msg_mutex);
}


int getMsg()
{
    int tmp;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&msg_mutex);
    tmp = _msg;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&msg_mutex);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Burgos - followed your suggestion and it does not appear to make a difference - will attempt other fixes.